# How to determine whether an Android View is an editable field without subclassing EditText?

Tags: android, view, webview, android-edittext

Is there a method in Android that allows you to get all editable fields from an InputConnection? I currently have a method that iterates through all focusables in a View and returns a list as

```
ArrayList<View> list = mTextView.getRootView().getFocusables();
```

and for every element in the list, I check

```
if (view instanceof EditText)
```

This works for all elements that subclass EditText, but it fails in the case of a browser/WebView, or if it's a class that subclasses TextView and builds an editable field from it.

Since InputConnection knows whether a field is editable, (the field can request focus no?), there has to be a way to iterate through all the views in the current view and get the ones that are editable. I tried calling the onCheckIsTextEditor() but that doesn't seem to work correctly. I'm wondering if anyone has tried this before and has potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursevaly see the hyearchy of views from parent to the childs.

if(child instanceof ViewGroup)
       checkEditables((ViewGroup) child);